# IndexBy nested object value of type array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am wanting to perform the below transformation, but am having trouble with how to do it, just wondering if anyone has any pointers:

```
//Source
[ 
   { types: ['a', 'b'] }, 
   { types: ['b'] }, 
   { types: ['a', 'c'] } 
]
//Transformation
{ 
   'a': [ { types: ['a', 'b'] }, { types: ['a', 'c'] }  ], 
   'b': [ { types: ['a', 'b'] }, { types: ['b'] } ],
   'c': [ { types: ['a', 'c'] } ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** with **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**

```js
var data = [{
  types: ['a', 'b']
}, {
  types: ['b']
}, {
  types: ['a', 'c']
}];

var res = data.reduce(function(a, b) {
  b.types.forEach(function(v) { // iterate over inner array
    a[v] = a[v] || []; // define the property if not defined
    a[v].push(b); // push the object refence 
  });
  return a;
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 3) + '</pre>');
```

For older browser check polyfill options of [forEch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill) methods.

Comment: Cool!!  we are on same page +1

Answer (score 0):

We can use `.reduce` of Array & iterate

```
var test = [ 
   { types: ['a', 'b'] }, 
   { types: ['b'] }, 
   { types: ['a', 'c'] } 
]

test.reduce(function(res,obj,index){
   obj.types.forEach(function(x){
     res[x] = res[x] || [];
     res[x].push(obj)
    });
  return res;
},{});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var data = [{
      types: ['a', 'b']
    }, {
      types: ['b']
    }, {
      types: ['a', 'c']
    }];

    var transform = function(records) {
     var obj = {};
     
     records.forEach(function(record){
      record.types.forEach(function(value){
                    obj[value] = obj[value] || []
          obj[value].push(record);
      });
     });
    
     return obj; 
    };

    document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(transform(data)) + '</pre>');
```